# Number of processors to assign to hyper-v guest in vmware workstation

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

I very confused about how vmware workstation assigns vcpus. I have a lab environment and I am running hyper-v nested inside vmware workstation. I am planning to run 2 virtual machines inside hyper-v for experimenting. How should I configure the cpu settings for the Hyper-v virtual machine so as to make sure that each vm created inside hyper-v can have a vcpu?

Windows Server 2012 R2 running inside vmware with hyper-v role installed, want to run 2 vms inside of hyper-v.

I am using Vmware Workstation 12. 
6 core amd processor.

Under processor the interface says "Number of processors and number of cores per processor. What are the correct settings to get this going?

Comment: there is no **correct answers** per say.  The more cores the faster it will go up to a point.  I would start with 1 processor and 1 core ea, and if it is dog slow make it 2 cores.  You don't state the M/Ghz of your CPU so its hard to tell.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test/prove in this lab environment.  Nesting hypervisors like this really isn't a good idea from a performance perspective.  **Anyway, if you don't know what you want to do, then just stick with the defaults** from the VM creation wizard.  The defaults are usually safe, and functional.

Comment: I want hyperv to see processors available to allocate to the vms. My processor is 3.3ghz